# Hyperlink in Javascript / Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, svg, hyperlink, coffeescript, justgage

I saw this on stackoverflow which works

```
a = document.createElement("a")
linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text")
a.appendChild linkText
a.title = "my title text"
a.href = "http://example.com"
document.body.appendChild a
```

I need something similar but my problem is that I'm using charts from here:

http://www.justgage.com

and I need the title of the chart to be a hyperlink!

In my coffeescript I have the following:

```
      p5 = new JustGage(
      id: p["name"]
      value: p["value"]
      min: 0
      max: 100
      title: (p["name"]).link p["url"] # My problem is here 
      )
```

Right now this is what I see: attached an image:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>test</a>
```

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: @muistooshort: It's using Raphael which is SVG-based, so no `<canvas>`-knowledge needed :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks, I had my canvas and SVG mixed up, turns out I don't know very much about either one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without modifying the library code. The relevant line would be [561](https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/blob/a8e733b601f04cfc136150e4a5c4832a8ee37d24/justgage.js#L561), just add a `href` property there (see [Raphael `Element.attr`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) for docs). Then make an additional parameter for the constructor function that allows you to pass arbitrary values.

If you don't want to do that, just omit the title and place a normal link above the drawing.

Comment: Can you tweak the `<tspan>` after it has been rendered? Might be easier than hacking the library for just one title.

Comment: @mu: You mean getting the Raphael canvas from the container element, selecting the `<tspan>` and giving it a href afterwards? Yeah, might be possible, but I've never worked with it so I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Thanks after all we've decided to go with bar charts!